# Set style in layout based on if user voted

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Ive made a page where people can vote arguments up or down. When they are logged in. But when they voted a argument they are not able to see if they have already voted an argument or not. For example if more then 1 person adding arguments into the list, you cant see whether you have already voted or not.

My Code is something like this:

```
Template.postArgument.events({
  'click .remove':function(event){
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();
    if(currentUserId === this.createdBy ) {
    event.preventDefault;
    var documentId = this._id;
    Arguments.remove({_id:documentId});
    }
  },

  'click':function() {
  Session.set('selected_argument', this._id);

  },
  'click .yes':function() {
      if(Meteor.user()) {
        var postId = Arguments.findOne({_id:this._id})
        if($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), postId.voted) !==-1) {
          return "Voted";
        } else {
    var argumentId = Session.get('selected_argument');
    Arguments.update(argumentId, {$inc: {'score': 1 }}); 
    Arguments.update(argumentId, {$addToSet: {voted: Meteor.userId()}});
        }
      }
  },
  'click .no':function() {
    if (Meteor.user())  {
      var postId = Arguments.findOne({_id:this._id})
      if ($.inArray(Meteor.userId(), postId.voted) !==-1) {
        return "Ok";
      } else {
      var argumentId = Session.get('selected_argument');
      Arguments.update(argumentId, {$inc: {'score': -1 }});
      Arguments.update(argumentId, {$addToSet: {voted : Meteor.userId()}});
      if (postId.score <= -3) {
        Arguments.remove({_id:this._id})
         }
       }
     }
  }
});
```

Now i want to change the background color of the button they clicked if they have voted. Like in Facebook. But the changed color should be only visable for the person which has voted. For everyone else nothing should change. 
How is this possble?

I tried something like `$(this).css('background-color', 'red');` after `var argumentId = Session.get('selected_argument');` 
but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this as an action, do it in your template:

```
<div class="someBaseClass {{#if voted}}votedClass{{/if}}">
  ...rest of your html
</div>
```

Then create a helper that returns true if the user has voted.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  voted: function(){
    var argument = Arguments.findOne(){_id: this._id});
    return argument.voted.indexOf(Meteor.userId) > -1;
  }
});
```